# How to get REST response body in java

Tags: java, rest

First time writing on Stackoverflow and a fairly new developer.
Trying my hands with REST API calls and wrote this little piece of code to use openweather API to get the temperature of cities.
I've kept the code clean but still think this is very verbose for the work it's doing but then I could be wrong. Any other tips from the developers on this code?
In particular I don't like the while loop to get the response body (but I couldn't find any other way to get the response body.) This method is something I read on Stackoverflow

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while(true) {
        try {
            
            /*
             * Getting the city name from the user
             */
            System.out.print("Enter the city name or enter exit to quit ");
            String cityName = sc.nextLine();
            
            /*
             * If the user enters exit, break the while loop
             */
            if(cityName.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) {
                System.out.println("exiting...");
                break;
            }
            
            /*
             * Open the connection and send the GET call
             */
            URL url = new URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityName.toLowerCase() + "&appid=" + Config.API_Key + "&units=metric");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            
            /*
             * Reading the response code from the connection
             * If the response code is 200, then read the Response Body
             */
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == 200) {
                
                String responseBody = "";
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
                
                while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                    responseBody += scanner.nextLine();
                }
                
                scanner.close();
                
                
                /*
                 * Use the JSONParser object to parse the response body and extract data
                 */
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(responseBody);
                
                JSONObject mainObject = (JSONObject) json.get("main");
                
                /*
                 * Getting the data needed and converting the String to Double
                 */
                Double tempInC = ((Number) mainObject.get("temp")).doubleValue();
                Double feelsLike = ((Number) mainObject.get("feels_like")).doubleValue();
                Double temp_min = ((Number) mainObject.get("temp_min")).doubleValue();
                Double temp_max = ((Number) mainObject.get("temp_max")).doubleValue();
                Double pressure = ((Number) mainObject.get("pressure")).doubleValue();
                Double humidity = ((Number) mainObject.get("humidity")).doubleValue();
                
                /*
                 * Printing out all data stored
                 */
                System.out.println("The current temperature for " + cityName + " is " + tempInC + " C");
                System.out.println("It feels like " + feelsLike + " C" + " in " + cityName);
                System.out.println("The minimum temperature for " + cityName + " is " + temp_min + " C");
                System.out.println("The maximum temperature for " + cityName + " is " + temp_max + " C");
                System.out.println("The air pressure for " + cityName + " is " + pressure + " kPa");
                System.out.println("The humidity level for " + cityName + " is " + humidity + " gm^3");
                
                System.out.println();
                
            }
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get is this

Enter the city name or enter exit to quit **Toronto**
The current temperature for Toronto is 18.63 C
It feels like 18.56 C in Toronto
The minimum temperature for Toronto is 17.49 C
The maximum temperature for Toronto is 20.06 C
The air pressure for Toronto is 1017.0 kPa
The humidity level for Toronto is 77.0 gm^3

Enter the city name or enter exit to quit **Dallas**
The current temperature for Dallas is 27.61 C
It feels like 29.6 C in Dallas
The minimum temperature for Dallas is 25.52 C
The maximum temperature for Dallas is 29.32 C
The air pressure for Dallas is 1017.0 kPa
The humidity level for Dallas is 67.0 gm^3

Enter the city name or enter exit to quit **Paris**
The current temperature for Paris is 19.94 C
It feels like 19.58 C in Paris
The minimum temperature for Paris is 16.34 C
The maximum temperature for Paris is 21.19 C
The air pressure for Paris is 1022.0 kPa
The humidity level for Paris is 61.0 gm^3

Enter the city name or enter exit to quit **exit**
exiting...

The response body looks like this

```
{
    "coord": {
    "lon": -79.4163,
    "lat": 43.7001
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 803,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "broken clouds",
        "icon": "04n"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 18.84,
    "feels_like": 18.76,
    "temp_min": 17.83,
    "temp_max": 20.06,
    "pressure": 1017,
    "humidity": 76
},
"visibility": 10000,
"wind": {
    "speed": 4.12,
    "deg": 70
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 75
},
"dt": 1660101834,
"sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 718,
    "country": "CA",
    "sunrise": 1660040128,
    "sunset": 1660091458
},
"timezone": -14400,
"id": 6167865,
"name": "Toronto",
"cod": 200
```

}

Comment: [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Move code into methods. One method should only do one thing.

Comment: url.openStream() is good to use - send that into the JSONParser directly.

Comment: as an option, you can pass the city as a parameter, and then read it from the array of the main method

Comment: Also wanted to know if reading the API key from a file instead of a static variable from a different class is better? I was thinking of loading up the entire configuration parameters (if applicable) in a HashMap and then read it from the HashMap directly?